# 2012 EGMO P7: Show that the lines $KH$, $EM$ and $BC$ are concurrent [ Proof Verification needed]

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, reflection, geometric-transformation

Let $ABC$ be an acute-angled triangle with circumcircle $\Gamma$ and orthocentre $H$. Let $K$ be a point of $\Gamma$ on the other side of $BC$ from $A$. Let $L$ be the reflection of $K$ in the line $AB$, and let $M$ be the reflection of $K$ in the line $BC$. Let $E$ be the second point of intersection of $\Gamma $ with the circumcircle of triangle $BLM$.
Show that the lines $KH$, $EM$ and $BC$ are concurrent. (The orthocentre of a triangle is the point on all three of its altitudes.)

Surely a very hard problem ! It took me 6 hrs to solve without any hints ! But this question is very diagram dependent, so if possible can someone verify my proof ? Thanks in advance.

Plus you can send your solution too, It helps me a lot.

**My Proof**: Now, let $X$ be the reflection of $H$ over side $BC$. It is well known that $ABCX$ is cyclic.

**Claim**: $BMHC$ and $LBHA$ are cyclic quads.

**Proof**: Note that $ABCK$ is cyclic ( It is given) . So $\angle BMC=\angle BKC= \angle BXC= \angle BHC$  and hence $BMHC$ is cyclic. Similarly, we can prove it for $LBHA$.

[image]

Let $MX\cap HK=Y$ . Note that by angle chase, we have  $Y \in BC$.

So it is enough to show that $E,M,X$ are collinear .

Now, since $BC$ is the perpendicular bisector of $MK$ and $AB$ is the perpendicular bisector of $LK$,  note that $B$ is the circumcentre of $\Delta KLM$ .

Define $I=MK\cap BC$ and $G= LK\cap AB$. Note that $BIGK$ is cyclic.

Now, we move to our next claim. ( Note: the Proof might look simple but it took me 4 hrs)

**Claim**: $L,M,H$ are collinear

Proof: Since $BIGK$ is cyclic, we get $\angle ABC=\angle GKI=\frac {1}{2} \angle LBM \implies \angle BML=90-\angle ABC$ .

So it is enough to show that $\angle HMB= 90+\angle ABC $ or $\angle HCB=90-\angle ABC$ (which is true by angle chase , $HC \perp AB$)
[image]

Now,the main proof .

**Claim**: $E,M,X$ are  collinear
[image]

**Proof**: Note that by using the cyclic quads $(BMHC)$, $(LBHA)$, $(ABCEX)$ and $(LBME)$, we note that

$\angle BEM=\angle MLB=\angle BLH=\angle BAH=\angle BAX= \angle BEH =\angle BEX$ .

Hence $\angle BEM=\angle BEX$. Hence  $EMX$ are collinear.

And we are done!

Comment: Hey! I haven't read your proof but why solving EGMO p7's . Note that INMO<<<<<EGMO

Comment: I read it up to just before the second claim --- why are you defining $I=MK\cap BK$?  Isn't it obvious $I=K$ then (and "BIGK" concyclic is trivial)?  By the way, you are missing the word "of " in "BC is the perpendicular bisector MK".

Comment: @user10354138 that is a typo .. I edited it , it should be $I=MK\cap BC$

Comment: @Raheel , INMO has become really hard..

Comment: ... and the first diagram has nothing to do with the solution, right?

Comment: umm.. It was just to show "How one can prove BHMC cyclic "

Comment: Hmm... that follows from the well-known result the reflection of the circumcircle in a side passes through the orthocenter, but OK it isn't too much of a problem.  The final displayed formula has a lot of typos in there.  It should be (omitting the angle signs) BEM=BLM=BLH=BAH=BAX=BEX.

Comment: @user10354138 Yes you are correct . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof relies on a following lemma (which is easy to prove):

**Lemma:** Reflection of $H$ across side of a triangle lies on circumcircle of that triangle.

Let $H'$ and $H''$ be respectively reflections of $H$ across $BC$ and $AB$. If we prove $E,M,H'$ are collinear we are done since $H'M$ and $HK$ meets in side $BC$.

Let $H'M$ and $H''L$ meet at point $F$. If we prove that $F$ lies on both circles we are done.

Let $\angle H'HC = x$, $\angle H'HK = y$ and $\angle MKB =z$.

- Circle $ABC$:

  Clearly $\angle HCB = 90-x$ and so $\angle BCH' = 90-x$. Also $\angle HH'F = y$ and $\angle H''HK = 180-x-y$ and thus $\angle FH''H = 180-x-y$. Since the sum of all angles in quadrilateral is $360$ we have (look at $H''HKF$) $\angle H''FK = 2x$ and thus $F$ is on circle $ABC$ (since $\angle H''CH' +\angle H''FH' =180$).
- Circle $MBL$:

  Since reflection preserves angles we have $\angle H'MB = y+z$ and $\angle BLF = y+z$ and we are done.

[image]

Comment: Great solution! I didn't think of reflecting H over AB .  I will remember this.